# how to select index value of listData in activeDropDownList in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have an array in a listData, I want to take the value by the activeDropDownList, not the index, here is my code:

```
$salaries=array('1000$', '2000$', '3000$', '4000$', '5000$');
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'salary', $salaries,
                               array('empty'=>'Select salary',
                               'style'=>'width:300px', 'class'=>'form-control'));
```

when the data sent to the controller the value of $model->salary = 1 if the user selected 2000$, I want the value to be 2000$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,    `array_combine`

```
$salaries=array_combine($salaries,$salaries);
```

You get the array `array('1000$'=>'1000$','2000$'=> '2000$','3000$'=> '3000$', '4000$'=> '4000$', '5000$'=> '5000$')`

Here is your should be ,

```
$salaries=array('1000$', '2000$', '3000$', '4000$', '5000$');
$salaries=array_combine($salaries,$salaries);
echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'salary', $salaries,
                               array('empty'=>'Select salary',
                               'style'=>'width:300px', 'class'=>'form-control'));
```